# How to calculate critical values ($W_{\alpha}$) for the Shapiro-Wilk test?

Tags: goodness-of-fit, normality-assumption

When performing the Shapiro-Wilk test, we can obtain the critical $W_{\alpha}$ statistic from tables, given $\alpha$ is 0.05 or 0.01.

If $\alpha$ is nonstandard, say 0.07 or 0.02 for example, how we can calculate the value of $W_{\alpha}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're asking how to calculate a critical value for the Shapiro-Wilk test at significance levels other than the usual tabulated ones (I mention this because it's possible you're really interested in how to compute a p-value, which is a closely related issue, though now Chris and I have edited your question, my doubt looks a bit odd.)

If your desired significance level is between tabulated ones, such as wanting 2% and having 5% and 1%, you could use [interpolation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/64538/how-do-i-find-values-not-given-in-interpolate-in-statistical-tables), which will at least be approximately suitable. It looks to me like $\Phi(1-p)$ is close to linear* in $\log(n(1-W))$ for $n\ge 12$, and even down at $n=5$ it's locally close enough that linear interpolation should work fine if done on those scales.

More generally, computer software is the most obvious choice. Some software offers direct calculation of p-values for the Shapiro-Wilk that may avoid the need to use critical values at all.

Finally, simulation is an option; one can simulate the statistic and hence obtain simulations from the distribution under the null; this allows one to compute estimates of quantiles of the distribution.

* Edit: looking at the p-value code in R, that shift in nearness-to-linearity between n=11 and n=12 is because R is using a different approximation to compute p-values for $n$ below 12; that shouldn't affect the suitability of linear interpolation at say 12, but it does suggest to me that it appearing to be very close to linear is more that the *approximation* is close to linear for $n\ge 12$; the actual transformed distribution is probably somewhat less linear down that low. [Now I look, the help even gives the information that a different approximation is used below 12.]

R also offers the following references, in case you want to write your own code:

[1] Patrick Royston (1982) An extension of Shapiro and Wilk's W test
     for normality to large samples.  *Applied Statistics*, *31*,
     115-124.

[2] Patrick Royston (1982) Algorithm AS 181: The W test for Normality.
     *Applied Statistics*, *31*, 176-180.

[3] Patrick Royston (1995) Remark AS R94: A remark on Algorithm AS
     181: The W test for normality.  *Applied Statistics*, *44*,
     547-551.

Answer (score 4):

I think this depends quite a lot on what you intend to do, and to what detail you would like to define your answer.  The $P$-value of the Shapiro-Wilk test is not a trivial thing to compute unfortunately. I'll give a simple answer to identify specific levels of $W_{\alpha}$ with a small degree of error, then we'll trace how you can actually calculate the $P$-value yourself.

### Quick and dirty method

Assuming that you are working in `R`, we can simply generate a number of data sets and test them until we find the actual value of $W$ that gives a particular $\alpha$ value. Note that $W_{\alpha}$ is dependant upon the sample size that you are using, so you will have to perform this method with your own sample size $n$.

We're going to basically generate a normally distributed random sequence of numbers of size $n$ with the function `rnorm(n)`, then calculate the $W$ statistic from `R` until we find one that we like.

```
find.W <- function(alpha = 0.05, error = 0.000001, n = 100){
  not.done <- TRUE
  while(not.done){
    a <- shapiro.test(rnorm(n))
    if(a$p.value < alpha+error && a$p.value > alpha-error){
      not.done = FALSE
      W <- a$statistic
    }
  }
  return(W)
}
```

Doing this once we find that for sample size 100, we find that

```
w <- find.W(alpha = 0.07, error = 0.001, n = 100); w
0.9765172
```

This is of course stochastic. If we repeat this 1000 times to get a better idea of the real number:

```
w <- vector()
for(i in 1:1000){
  w[i] <- find.W(alpha = 0.07, error = 0.001, n = 100)
}
mean(w); sd(w)

[1] 0.9764422
[1] 4.544819e-05
```

We find that for $\alpha = 0.07$, $W_{\alpha} \approx 0.9764$. If we look into it a little bit further, we find that this is only an approximation of the true $W$ statistic. To find the real value $W$ value, let's trace how this one is calculated.

#### Theoretical value of $W$

If we look into the source code for `R`, we can pretty easily find how the $W$ statistic is calculated. Looking at the source of the `shapiro.test()` function, we find that it calls a `C` file named `S_Wilks.c`. Looking into it, we find the source code [here](http://www.matrixscience.com/msparser/help/group___shapiro_wilk_source_code.html) [1]. Inside the code, a paper gets referenced with the theoretical aspect. After a little digging, it appears that the approximation method comes from [this](http://www.jstor.org.proxy.bib.uottawa.ca/stable/2347291?seq=4#page_scan_tab_contents) [2,3] paper. You can read this yourself if you would like to know the actually theoretical aspects to manually calculated $P$-values. The methods used in the original Shapiro & Wilk 1965 paper are from an unpublished manuscript that has since been lost to time (at least, I can't find it).

[1] Source code which `R` uses: http://www.matrixscience.com/msparser/help/group___shapiro_wilk_source_code.html

[2] Approximation of $W$ paper: 
**Some Techniques for Assessing Multivarate Normality Based on the Shapiro- Wilk W**, J. P. Royston, Journal of the Royal Statistical Society. Series C (Applied Statistics), Vol. 32, No. 2 (1983), pp. 121-133

[3] Approximation of $W$ technique: **Statistical Algorithms: Algorithm AS**, J. P. Royston, Journal of the Royal Statistical Society. Series C (Applied Statistics), Vol. 32, No. 2 (1983), pp. 176-180

Archive on JSTOR found [here](http://ftp.math.utah.edu/pub/tex/bib/toc/as1980.html#31(2):1982) for that particular issue.

Comment: is there a method to calculate it with a simple scientific calculator?

Comment: If you read [@Glen_b's answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/172154/44952), he links to a [linear interpolation](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/64538/how-do-i-find-values-not-given-in-interpolate-in-statistical-tables) method that you could perform using a calculator, but it would not be optimal.

Comment: Mohammad -- For largish $n$ (say bigger than 30 or so), the transformed relationship I mention should be adequate even for moderate extrapolation outside the tabulated values, assuming you have decent normal tables (or a normal cdf function - and its inverse - on your calculator; some do). Of course, the algorithms given by Royston can in principle be performed on a calculator.

Comment: If you're looking to perform this calculation on a calculator, I would definitely go with what @Glen_b has mentioned. Thanks by the way Glen_b, I learned a lot from reading your answer and the linear interpolation method.