# How to interpolate for degrees of freedom from a $ \chi^{2} $ table

Tags: chi-squared-test

The question asks to find $ \chi^{2*} $ that cuts off 5% of the tail with df=52. the chart given lists df=50 then jumps to 60

Comment: You may want to remove the `*` from your body text as well.  Your question is covered in the answer here: [How do I find values not given in (interpolate in) statistical tables?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/64538/how-do-i-find-values-not-given-in-interpolate-in-statistical-tables/64539#64539)

Comment: in the title it was an error, in the question it just means a specific value of $\chi^2$ opposed to the whole range

Comment: It's probably more confusing than enlightening. I'd suggest  "find the $\chi^2$ value that..."

Comment: When you say "the question asks" .... is this for a class?

Comment: Specifically, note that for degrees of freedom for $t$, $\chi^2$ and $F$ the linked answer recommends linear interpolation in $1/\text{df}$ rather than in $\text{df}$. However in this particular case, linear interpolation in $\text{df}$ is actually very good, slightly better than inverse interpolation in df; I'd stick with that for this case (which is what the first half of the linked post is about).

Answer (score -2):

I would take the data from df=50 in this case. If it was 55--> average

Comment: (-1) This is not interpolation at all. If you're going to average for $df=55$, which *is* (linear) interpolation, then why not linearly interpolate for $df=52$? Why introduce such an inconsistency, especially when the error made when replacing $52$ by $50$ is substantial?