# How to choose critical F value from statistical tables when the df is large?

Tags: anova, f-test, tables, f-distribution

For an F(2, 237) distribution, how should I determine a critical F value from a statistical table? Would I look up (2, 150) or (2, 300)? Should it simply be the closest degrees of freedom?

Comment: Why not just calculate it?

Comment: One can use [interpolation](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/64538/how-do-i-find-values-not-given-in-interpolate-in-statistical-tables). In this case, interpolation in the reciprocal of degrees of freedom works very well, yielding about 5 figure accuracy in this region of the table at typical significance levels. There's an F example there.

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, I have to use the table to compare