# Anova one way (getting different p-values in calculator and F table). Why?

Tags: anova

I am resolving an anova one-way exercise. But I am doubtful because when using the F-table to get the p-value, I am getting a probability around 2.2 (an obvious error), but if I use a calculator the probability is 0.042.

I have an independent variable with 4 levels. The mean and standard deviation are this:

```
N         Mean         Standard Deviation
10         4.3          2.2
10         3.8          1.6
10         4.9          1.9
10         6.3          2.1
```

I did these calculations:

Grand mean =  4.8.

Sum of squares between groups = 35.07.

Sum of squares within groups =  138.7.

The degrees of freedom between groups is 3, the degree of freedom within groups is 36.

So with this I get a value of 3.

With this f value I check the  f table for a 5% of significance level, using a degree of freedom of 3 in the numerator and 36 in the denominator and the value in the table is around 2.2. So I'm not understanding why I get 2.2 and the calculator gives 0.042. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Using a calculator, I get moreless the same values for everything only the p is different, is 0.042. For example in the calculator the f is also 3.033.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The value you're looking up in the table is a critical value, not a p-value. There's no contradiction when they differ since they're not at all the same thing.

(However, at the 5% level you mention, I don't get a critical value of 2.2 when I look up an F with 3 and 36 df. Instead I get 2.866. Did you mistakenly look up the 10% critical value?)

Note that when you looked up the table *your data values didn't come into what you looked up at all*. Only the degrees of freedom and the significance level. What you looked up is the smallest F value that would be significant at the 5% level, which you compare your F with; if it's at least that large, you have a significant F. (That F value is 2.87. Your F value was 3.03 which was larger than it, so you would reject the null if you did it that way)

This is completely consistent with getting a p-value below 0.05:

[image: Density for F(3,36) showing 5% critical value and calculated F, as well as the shaded area to the right of the calculated F which is the p-value of 0.042]

We can see that there are two ways you can get the outcome of the hypothesis test:

(i) see if the F value is greater than the critical F from the table

(ii) see if the p-value is less than the significance level.

You can do whichever one of the two is convenient (done correctly, they give identical reject/don't reject decisions).

In general, if you have a p-value (say from computer output), you will compare that with the significance level, but if you are working "by hand" and have only tables, compare the F with the F critical value. Note that if you're using tables you often need to [get values not in the table](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/64538/how-do-i-find-values-not-given-in-interpolate-in-statistical-tables).

Comment: Thanks. Yes I was checking at 10%, but the table just shows values for df of 30 and then df of 40, I need for a df of 36, but yes itt should be arround 2.8 because 40 it is 2.83.

Comment: But so for example in anova we compare always the f statistics with the critical value? We dont compare the probability with the level of significance, for example compere 0.05 with 0.042. Or we can do both ways?

Comment: see update at end of answer

Answer (score 0):

Your table value  is 2.2.  Compare the computed value of  F= 3 with  2.2. This suggests signficant effect at alpha = 5%..You need to check that .042 is some value that you have generated. May be it is p-value.
You should know that F-table   does not show  p-values. It incorporates  only F values.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So we need to compare to f and not with the p value? For example in a two sample t test, when we calculate the test statistic we get a t and we go to the table to check the p that corresponds to the obtained t and then we compare that probability with the significance level. In anova its not like that? In anova we compare that 2.2 or 0.052(in calculator) with f and not with the significance level of 5%?

Comment: If computed F is greater than table value at a specified significance level, it would imply that there is significant effect. May be you have another question in your mind . let it be in question form rather than putting it as a comment.