# I have a t-statistic of -1.06 how do I find the p-value by hand?

Tags: self-study, p-value, inference

I keep seeing this in my econometrics book. "The t-statistic is -1.06 which is not significant at even the x% level against the two-sided alternative". This happens at exercises for which I have to do the calculations by hand. How can I find the p-value by hand. My idea is that if I have t-stat of -1.06 I go in the z-table and look at -1.0 and 6 (in the column) but how do I know the 2-sided value and what happens if the t-stat is -1.055?

Also, totally unrelated to the questions. I find it quite difficult to study for my econometrics exam. Like I read, but nothing stays with me. I would really appreciate any advice on how you guys are studying for exams (I have a more humanistic background and I am not used to study numerical subjects).

Thank you!

Comment: The second half of your question is not really on-topic here. I'm not sure there is an SE that could help you. But suggestions on exam preparation and study habits are just a Google search away.

Comment: You can't do it by hand unless you have the t table memorized.

Comment: @Michael It's easy enough to do with pencil and paper in just a minute or two using various techniques, such as Simpson's Rule. One can even test against critical values almost instantly, using mental arithmetic and a minimum of memorization. Consider the 68-95-99.7 rule, which provides *lower bounds* for the p-value. In this case, the t-statistic of -1.06 already indicates that the p-value is close to or greater than 100-68 = 32%, regardless of the number of degrees of freedom.  (In fact, computer calculation shows the correct value is between 29% and 40%.)

Comment: I don't think it can be done exactly.

Comment: Your question is really unclear, but you seem to me to be asking about [how to interpolate in tables](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/64538/how-do-i-find-values-not-given-in-interpolate-in-statistical-tables). Is that the kind of thing you're after? Your unrelated question should be removed; it's a completely separate issue (and probably not suitable to our site as Sycorax suggests)

Comment: @Michael Any calculation of a p-value will be an approximation. Looking up tables certainly isn't exact either. As long as it's done to sufficient accuracy for the purpose at hand, there's no difficulty with approximation. [It's not all that difficult to compute bounds on the error should that prove necessary, but it's usually not needed. If one computes the p-value to be 0.231, it really doesn't matter if the exact answer would have been 0.22873472... ; there's rarely any benefit in knowing more than a couple of figures unless you're near a significance level]

Answer (score 0):

To get the two sides $\alpha$, divide by 2. If you want the p value for - 1.055 check the value for 1.055 since t-table is symmetric.

Edit: I guess there are no. 005 values in the table so just take the the two next to 1.055 and divide by 2.

Comment: This might be right but it depends on the particular table you are using. The correct answer is to use the t distribution table with the appropriate number of degrees of freedom which would be n-2 where n is the sample size.

Comment: Oh right was reading too fast. Change normal to t-dist.

Comment: @MichaelChernick: Take care not to assume a particular application when the OP hasn't mentioned one - $n-2$ wouldn't be the correct no. degrees of freedom to use in a one-sample t-test for example.